# Get a List buckets react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xhtml, autodesk-forge

I am trying to learn and produce something at the same time. 
This is an example of code for a component that should read buckets and produce a list of them. On the paper the `console.log` is working, but I can get the code to save that list into a variable that I can use to produce the `XHTML` list.

```js
    class ListBuckets extends React.Component{

        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                listBuckets: []
            };

            this.GetBuckets = this.GetBuckets.bind(this);
        }

        GetBuckets(){
            let tmpCmp = this;
            var BucketsApi = new ForgeSDK.BucketsApi(); //Buckets Client
            // Get the buckets owned by an application.
            // Use the oAuth2TwoLegged client object and the credentials object that were
            // obtained from the previous step
            // notice that you need do add a bucket:read scope for the getBuckets to work
            BucketsApi.getBuckets({}, null, tmpCmp.props.credentials)
            .then(function(buckets){         
                console.log(buckets.body.items);
            }, function(err){
                console.error(err);
            });
        }

        render(){
            return (
                <div className="card" style={{width: '18rem'}, {margin: "10px"}}>
                    <div className="card-body">
                        <h5 className="card-title bg-dark text-white" style={{padding: "5px"}}><FaFolder/> Buckets</h5>
                        <h6 className="card-subtitle">List of buckets</h6>
                        <p className="card-text">
                            This card provides a list of available buckets
                        </p>

                        {
                        this.props.credentials!==null 
                            ? <ul>{this.GetBuckets()}</ul>
                            : <div>
                                <div className="spinner-border spinner-border-sm"></div>
                                <span> Waiting for credentials...</span>
                            </div>
                                }
                    </div>
                </div>
        )   

        }
    }
```

Can ayone help me through this?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to store or return `buckets.body.items` from the `GetBuckets()` function. You haven't done anything with them here, so they just get discarded after the function runs. Use `setState()` to store them in component state once you receive them:

```js
GetBuckets(){
    let tmpCmp = this;
    var BucketsApi = new ForgeSDK.BucketsApi();
    BucketsApi.getBuckets({}, null, tmpCmp.props.credentials)
        .then(function(buckets){         
            console.log(buckets.body.items);
            // The important thing happens here:
            this.setState({ listBuckets: buckets.body.items });
        }, function(err){
            console.error(err);
        });
}
```

Secondly, this function is going to get called every time the component re-renders, so you may only want to call it inside a one of the component lifecycle methods like `componentDidMount()`. Since it's an async function, you may have to do some null-checking in later in your render function.

Lastly, you can't just stick this array into your render function and expect it to return a an `<li>` for each element in the array. You need to map over the objects and return some JSX:

```js
...
{
    this.props.credentials!==null 
        ? <ul>
              {this.state.listBuckets.map(bucket => 
                  <li>bucket.data</li>)}</ul>}
        : <div>
            <div className="spinner-border spinner-border-sm"></div>
            <span> Waiting for credentials...</span>
          </div>
}
```

Comment: The `this.setState()` call inside the success callback for `getBuckets` doesn't seem right. You'd probably want to use fat arrow functions, or store the `setState` function outside of the `getBuckets` call.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what @tobiasfried said:

Using Forge SDKs on the client side is not recommended as it could potentially expose the Forge application credentials. A better practice is to provide your own server endpoint which makes the Forge API calls and returns data in any format your client app needs. Take a look at the [Learn Forge](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewmodels) tutorial and its [Node.js sample](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels/tree/nodejs). The specific endpoint that lists all available buckets is [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels/blob/nodejs/routes/oss.js#L39-L73).